# Alter reg-ex for email Validation on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, regex

I am trying to validate email using reg-ex. here is the code...

```
+ (BOOL) stringIsValidEmail:(NSString *)checkString;
{
    NSString *emailRegEx =
    @"(?:[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}"
    @"~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\"
    @"x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-"
    @"z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5"
    @"]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-"
    @"9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21"
    @"-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx]; 

    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:checkString];
}
```

now I don't have much knowledge about regex but this accepts a@a.c as a valid email. But this should not be the case and at least two characters should be required at the end. What paramater do I need to change in this so it returns false. I have hit and tried but that didn't work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I believe you can set number of characters criteria with something like {2} or {3}. Explore in that direction.

Comment: Do not do that and see:
[Validating emails with regex][1]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: As Rikkles's link highlights, it's not really possible to completely validate an email address with a regex.  It *might* be useful in some cases to use a regex for a simple/crude validation.  But that all depends on what you are trying to do.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @dan1111 i am validating this on iPhone so that server side validation runs can be minimised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too much symbols, you can try this

```
- (BOOL) IsValidEmail:(NSString *)checkString {
    BOOL sticterFilter = YES; 
    NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSString *laxString = @".+@.+\\.[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
    NSString *emailRegex = sticterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:checkString];
}
```

Comment: You can write it simpler, instead of `[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*`, just write `[A-Za-z]{2,}`. `{2,} means match 2 or more.`

Answer (score 1):

Try using this as regex

```
NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
```

the {2,4} especially validates that the ending characters should be alphabets and more than two in count

Comment: That doesn't allow IDNA. You should allow dashed and numbers in the TLD also. Better yet, just check that there is an @ sign (and a dot somewhere after it, if you must) or even better, abandon this doomed endeavor.